# Find a function $g$ so that $g(x)F(x,y)$ is conservative where $F(x,y)=(x^2+y^2+x)\; i \; + xy \; j$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Find a function $g$ so that $g(x)\textbf{F}(x,y)$ is conservative where
>   $$\textbf{F}(x,y)=(x^2+y^2+x)\ \textbf{i} + xy \ \textbf{j}$$

I tried to use cross partials test

But it isn't helping since I don't know the form of $g(x)$

How do we solve such questions ?

Comment: A vector field is conservative if $\nabla \times F = 0$. In 2D this simplifies to $\frac{\partial F_y}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial F_x}{\partial y} = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\textbf{A}(x,y) = g(x) \textbf{F}(x,y)$ be a conservative vector field, then
$$ |\nabla \times \textbf{A}| = \frac{\partial A_y}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial A_x}{\partial y} = 0 \tag{1} $$

where

$$ \frac{\partial A_x}{\partial y} = g(x) \frac{F_x}{\partial y} = 2y \ g(x) $$

$$ \frac{\partial A_y}{\partial x} = g'(x) F_y + g(x) \frac{F_y}{\partial x} = xy \ g'(x) + y \ g(x) $$

Plugging both into $(1)$ we have

$$ x \ g'(x) - \ g(x) = 0  $$

This is a first-order separable ODE that you can solve